# Convert all sectioning of a document (or part of it) to the corresponding hierarchically higher one (in TexStudio)

Tags: sectioning, chapters, parts

I wrote a document which has now around 120 pages. As I'm new to Latex, I started writing the document without using the sectioning `\part` (as I didn't know it existed). So the higher hierarchical sectioning of the document is `chapter` instead of `\part`. Is there an easy way (in `Texstudio` for example) to systematically convert all sectioning of a document (or **part of it**) to the corresponding hierarchically higher one according to the following scheme:

```
\chapter{} ==> \part{}
\section{} ==> \chapter{} 
\subsection{} ==> \section{}
\subsubsection{} ==> \subsection{}
\paragraph{} ==> \subsubsection{}
\subparagraph{} ==> \paragraph{}
```

Comment: You could use the replace function (accessible via the shortcut CTrl+R)  and replace `\chapter{`by `\part{` and `\section{` by `\chapter{`...

Comment: indeed. That was easy... many thanks @leandriis

Comment: Or easier still if you shift stuff around regularly is to right click on heading in structure pane and say indent (or unindent) and the underlying heading levels should follow.